# CSS selector problem.  Any ideas how to select this?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want a new `<div>` to appear on thumbnail hover.

You can inspect my code on http://techgeek.lt/naudinga/

This works:

```
 #main:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

but it hovers on `#main`.

I already tried (and no luck):

```
img.thumbnail:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

#main img.thumbnail:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

.thumbnail:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

img.thumbnail:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

img.thumbnail .alignleft:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

.thumbnail .alignleft:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

#main.thumbnail .alignleft:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

#main.thumbnail .alignleft img:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

.thumbnail .alignleft img:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
}

.thumbnail img:hover  .whitewrapper {
  display: block;
```

Comment: You sure tried a lot of stuff!

Comment: @Lokys: "Please fix all my code" is generally not an acceptable "question" on this site - see the FAQ. Please narrow down and clarify. But for starters - fix your `<script>` tags - they all give 404s.

Comment: Gustav, what do you mean by "fix script tags"? It seems like they work fine for me..

Comment: Here's [one dead script tag](http://techgeek.lt/naudinga/js/jquery-1.6.2.js) and there's a bunch more.  Also, you need to "include" jQuery **before** the plugins.  And you seem to have curly quotes inside the `<link rel="image_src"...` element.

Comment: Your entire page is also missing the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags.  I've never seen the [W3C Validator choke on a page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftechgeek.lt%2Fnaudinga%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) before... no doubt from the `�` symbols (curly quotes?) on line 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
.post-more a:first-child:hover ~ .whitewrapper, .whitewrapper:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Both [`:first-child`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild) and the [general sibling combinator (`~`)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) are supported in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

---

You need to fix that first `a` in each post:

```
<div class="post-more"> 
    <a href=".." onclick=".."<a title=".." href=".." >..</a></a>
```

that's broken HTML, which causes the selector I've provided to fail in some browsers.

Comment: Note that I've updated my answer since I first posted it. Grab the newer version of the selector, it solves an issue with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks again! I would love to have such css skills in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [+ selector type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

If the div comes directly after the img, this should work:

```
img.thumbnail:hover + .whitewrapper {
   display: block;
}
```

Update: I tested it and it works for me.  Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMxd2/5/).